# How I can use java.applet.Applet in Android?

Tags: java, android

When I try to use java.applet.Applet, I get a runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet
```

I have tried to put that library manually, but I get the same error.
I have done the same with other libraries and it worked, but not with this one.

Comment: Android browsers do not support applets. I believe no mobile browsers do. Unlike iOS or Windows Phone, Android does have a Java VM, but it is neither binary nor API compatible with Sun's.

Comment: Actually, Android does **not** have a Java VM. It has the Dalvik VM which can execute Dalvik bytecode that gets produced *from* Java Bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to use java.applet.Applet, I get a runtime error

That is because that class does not exist in Android.

> I have tried to put that library manually

`java.applet.Applet` is a class. It is not a library.

> How I can use java.applet.Applet in Android?

You don't. Most likely, you rewrite the code to use the Android UI framework, the same as if you had a Swing or SWT Java desktop application, or a Java servlet.